# How to set date formatter for the date structure "2014-04-01T13:30:00.000+0000"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm new in objective C. I want to set a date formatter for converting date "2014-04-01T13:30:00.000+0000" to another format - "2014/04/01 13:30:00 AM".

I have already tried many formats, but its not working. Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Here you go. Great bookmark http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date%5FFormat%5FPatterns

Comment: Create a `NSDateFormatter`

Use `setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a"`

Create a string from your date

Comment: Show us your best effort.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - I think he's having trouble reading the first format.

Comment: @HotLicks - yes. you are right. i need NSDateFormatter format to read that date string. Please help.

Comment: @HotLicks: another anup solved this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *dateFormat1 = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ";
NSString *dateFormat2 = @"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss a";

NSString *dateString = @"2014-04-01T13:30:00.000+0000";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat1];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat2];
dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"Date : %@",dateString);
```

Comment: Thankz Buddy.. Its Working Perfectly. Thankz lot for your valuable answer and time..

Comment: it will not work  NSString *dateFormat1 = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";  should be like this

Answer (score 1):

use below format, will work... :)

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

[for more ref see this.](http://iphonesdkhelps.blogspot.in/2009/06/date-from-string-and-vice-versa.html)

Answer (score 0):

This code works well for me and think works for you too..

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a"];
 NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
 NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
 [dateFormat release];
```

If it doesn't work for you..Feel free to ask..Just comment..

Comment: you can also check this link.. http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns